# Why does flow give an uncovered code warning when using instanceof?

Tags: javascript, string, flowtype

Flow gives uncovered code warning for the `str` in second if statement.

> [flow coverage] uncovered code
>     (parameter) str: never
>     [Flow]
>     str: empty

```
const isStr = (str: string): boolean=> {
  if(typeof str === 'string')
    return true;
  if(str instanceof String)
    return true
  return false
}
```

But if the if statements are reversed it doesn't give any warnings.

```
const isStr = (str: string): boolean=> {
  if(str instanceof String)
    return true
  if(typeof str === 'string')
    return true;
  return false
}
```

Is it because `typeof str === 'string'` is always true if `str instanceof String` is true, but the reversed is not always right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to JavaScript's definition of strings. Try this in your console:

```
var str = 'foo';
typeof str;
// result: "string"

str instanceof String;
// result: false

var Str = new String('bar');
typeof Str;
// result: "object"

Str instanceof String;
// result: true
```

Basically, in JavaScript, regular strings are not actually `String` instances (like they are in Java), but rather string primitives. Since in your function you explicitly declare the argument as a `string` (primitive), the first condition will always be true, hence the second condition is dead code. If you switch them, `str instanceof String` will always be false, so the second condition is still live.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to also define str as instance of String class?

Comment: No, the `String` class is basically an object wrapper around a primitive. If you're familiar with Java, it's like `int` versus `Integer`.

Comment: This one works `const isStr = (str: string | String): boolean=>` am I missing anything?

Comment: Ah okay, if you're referring to the type declaration in the signature, then yeah, that works. I mean that in actual code you can't create a variable that's a primitive but also an instance of `String`